# Is HDMI 1.4 backwards compatible with 1.3?

Tags: hdmi

I'm installing a Hitachi MS-1 switcher, and it's HDMI output works fine with an HDMI v1.3 cable, but not with a cable v1.4.  I've tested the v1.4 cable on a different output device (DVD player) and it works fine.  I've also tried two different display devices (monitor and projector).

My question is:  Is HDMI v1.4 supposed to be fully backwards compatible, or are there some caveats?

Also, has anyone else encountered any equipment that worked with HDMI v1.3 but not v1.4?

Answer (score 1):

A 1.4 cable should work fine with a 1.3 signal, however an HDMI 1.4 signal will not work with an HDMI 1.3 cable or an HDMI 1.3 output unless the source is capable of using a prior standard.